# Exception after flutter create

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter,

Right after creating my second app:

```
flutter create myapp && cd myapp && flutter run
```

I'm getting this exception. And although the app with the simple counter works in emulator, this exception doesn't look healthy, right?

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
I/flutter ( 6000): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6000): The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
I/flutter ( 6000): There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
I/flutter ( 6000): Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must
I/flutter ( 6000): have a unique non-null tag.                          
I/flutter ( 6000): In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <default FloatingActionButton tag>
...

(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #141    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1049:9)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #142    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #146    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)          
    I/flutter ( 6000): #147    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)        
    I/flutter ( 6000): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)            
    I/flutter ( 6000): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    I/flutter ( 6000): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    I/flutter ( 6000): The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
    I/flutter ( 6000): HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403,                
    I/flutter ( 6000): https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/10/21/34/woman-1320810_960_720.jpg
    I/flutter ( 6000):                                                      
    I/flutter ( 6000): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:   
    I/flutter ( 6000): #0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:90:9)
    I/flutter ( 6000): <asynchronous suspension>                            
    I/flutter ( 6000): #1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #2      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
...

(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #213    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #214    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #215    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #216    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #217    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #218    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #219    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #220    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #221    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:163:11)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #222    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:477:7)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #223    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:232:7)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #224    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:391:14)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #225    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1584:7)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #226    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #227    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:344:19)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #228    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:774:13)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #229    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #230    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #231    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #232    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
    I/flutter ( 6000): #236    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)          
    I/flutter ( 6000): #237    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)        
    I/flutter ( 6000): (elided 6 frames from package dart:async)            
    I/flutter ( 6000):                                                      
    I/flutter ( 6000): Image provider:                                      
    I/flutter ( 6000):   NetworkImage("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/10/21/34/woman-1320810_960_720.jpg", scale:
    I/flutter ( 6000):   1.0)                                               
    I/flutter ( 6000): Image key: NetworkImage("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/10/21/34/woman-1320810_960_720.jpg",
    I/flutter ( 6000):   scale: 1.0)                                        
    I/flutter ( 6000): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    I/flutter ( 6000): Another exception was thrown: There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        26.5s
    ✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
    Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...                         8.8s
    Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...                    
    10,951ms (!)
```

Do you have any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Its probably showing the previous error from another project. Recently after `flutter upgrade` I got this kind of weird error

Comment: @VijayaRagavan same here, it happened after `flutter upgrade`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starter Flutter app doesn't contain things like loading network images as it's just a simple counter app. As Vijaya said, it's probably just an old error from another project. I get the same stuff when I use `flutter run`. Unless you edited the `flutter create` template, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin but it's a bare new project right after `flutter create`. How could it reflect any remnants of another projecct?

Comment: I'm not too sure, this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45478 seems to state it's fixed on the latest master branch. To switch, use `flutter channel master` but be warned, it's a pretty unstable branch. I'd wait a while for it to come out on at least beta.